# Wordpress Jquery Animation without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, animation

so i made a wordpress site with some animations in it that work fine. 
They only work when i scroll the site and look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  


    $(window).scroll( function(){

        if(!isMobile) {
        $('.animate_1').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({opacity:'1', margin: '0 3% 0 3%'},2000, 'easeInOutQuart');

            }   

        })
        } 
        })
    });
```

This works perfectly fine. Now i want to animate a class which i call ".aniamte_2" just when the site is loaded, without any scrolling or clicking. I tried it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  

                $('.animate_2').animate({opacity:'1', margin: '0 3% 0 3%'},2000, 'easeInOutQuart');  
    });
```

It did not work for some reason. Chrome told me that "$" is undefiend or something.

Someone has an idea how i can animate this without scrolling?

Comment: Try loading jquery in head, at least for debug

Comment: put second `JS` in footer and make sure any other library is not loading before this, because error clearly says it's not able to find `$`.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser can't recognize $ it's a good indication that jQuery isn't loading; there are numerous reasons why this might be the case.

Comment: it starts giving me this error only after i include the second part of my code. Without it everything works fine.

Comment: @BooooomxD could you include the rest of your code? If you put the complete js as it looks after including the new function call and the html it relates to it'd be easier to see where it's going wrong.